# MVC 4 - Show Item Details in the same page for single row

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, button, partial-views

The question I have is how can I show the details of a selected movie when clicking on Details link on the same page? Currently when you click on the hyperlink you are redirected to the controller and action that will display the info about that movie such as `Movies/Details/1`. I would like it to be displayed on `Movies`

I used the sample code located here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MVC5-Demo-with-Entity-c6bc81df to create my MVC application.

It uses CRUD create read, update and delete records.

The reason for this is I am creating a website to be used with buttons to display the appropriate data in the database for example Button1 - ID1, Button2 - ID2 etc....

Is this possible to details on the same page where movies are listed?

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</td>
        <td>
        <a href='@Url.Action("Details", new { id = item.ID })' class="ajax">Details</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>

<div id="TargetDiv"></div>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".ajax").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var elementUrl = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                url: elementUrl,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#TargetDiv').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**MovieController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcMovie.Models;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
    {
        public class Movies2Controller : Controller
        {
            private Jess_MoviesEntities db = new Jess_MoviesEntities();
            public ActionResult Index()
            {return View(db.Movies.ToList());}

            public ActionResult OneMovie(int id)
            {return View();}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your view

Comment: @DonaldJansen I have added in the view code above. Any other code needed let me know.

Comment: I added an answer that might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your _Layout.cshtml

Reason: Put it in the _Layout.cshtml then you can reuse it on other views

Put this just after jquery

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ajax").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var elementUrl = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                url: elementUrl,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#TargetDiv').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In your view add a div somewhere `<div id="TargetDiv"></div>`

Then replace the following line

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID })
```

With

`<a href='@Url.Action("Details", new { id=item.ID })' class="ajax">Details</a>`

Let me know if you manage to get it working.

Be sure to make your 'Details' view a partial view otherwise you might end up adding the _Layout.cshtml in the target dive

Explanation
This will prevent the normal redirection to happen `e.preventDefault()`
After that it will take the url eg `Details/1` and with Ajax it will get the result and put the result in the same page inside the div with id `TargetDiv`

**EDIT:**

Use your current Index.cshtml

Create a new view
Details.cshtml

with the following content: (you can change it when needed)

```
@model MvcMovie.Models.Movie

<h2>Index for @Model.Title</h2>
```

No edit your controller and add the ActionResult Details()

```
public class Movies2Controller : Controller
{
    private Jess_MoviesEntities db = new Jess_MoviesEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Movies.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult OneMovie(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        //get model from database
        return PartialView(db.Movies.First(x => x.ID == id));
    }
}
```

Comment: do I need to create a new page called _Layout.cshtml as that code came from my Index.cshtml?

Comment: With that link its taking me to Details/Details/id.. I have added the code like you said. The link and the div on Index.cshtml, javascript under _Layout and nothing on the controller. anyideas?

Comment: If you don't have a _Layout.cshtml you can put it directly into your view. I also edited my answer

Comment: What code needs to be in the details partial view? At the moment it is currently empty.

Comment: the details partial view is your html code that you want to display. so thats what you want to display for the selected item

Comment: currently when I click on details nothing happens. and I think this is as I don't have a partial view, can you edit my code above or your code to show the partial view please/

Comment: On my original question I have added the code beneath my moviecontroller and index.cshtml. :) Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: Ok give me a few min to type it all

Comment: ok no problem, are you amending it on yours or mine as it would be great if you add it to mine :)

Comment: Donald, were you able to edit the code like you suggested?

Comment: Yeah I am busy with it, sorry im also at work so I have to do in beteween

Comment: no worries at all I completely understand and appreciate your help to get this working :)

Comment: Check if that does anything

Comment: perfect that your for your help with this its very much appreciated :)

Comment: My Pleasure, Im glad I could help

Comment: I am sure there will be more and as developing and learning all of the time :)

Comment: my only further question is to how I change the title for example details to be different depending on the button I click e.g. 1, 2, 3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109563/discussion-between-terrortot38-and-donald-jansen).

Answer (score 2):

if you familiar with jquery and ajax you can use it.

for example :

```
 $("MyLick").click(function(){ 
         $.post("/MyDetailUrl",{Id:5},function(content){alert(content);});

});
```

it just an example, you can find lots of solutions.

**EDIT Post**

follow this step in new project and after that do the same in your project.

1-Create 2 Actions in your Controller

```
public ActionResult Index() // To Show the Main Movie Page
{
    return View();
}

Public ActionResult ShowDetail(int id) //To Show Detail information
{
    // Do the Database operations to retrive movie information
    return Content("This is my Detail information");
}
```

2- In Index.cshtml File of your controller

```
<input type="button" id="showDetail"><span>Show Detail</span></input>

<div id="detailBox"></div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>

$("#showDetail").click(function(){ 
         $.post("/Movie/ShowDetail",{Id:5},function(content){$("#detailBox").html(content)});

});
```

Comment: try to use,it's very nice and easy
www.jquery.com

Comment: can you show an example of how I would add this into my code?

Comment: i've show you, read my answer and do the same.
my example code send and id 5 to the action and return a result

Comment: Does this go in the Model/View/Controller that's what I'm not clear on :) sorry for the confusion.

Comment: what do you mean by go in the Model/View/Controller (MVC).
it's just a javascript code

Comment: How do I call this script from a button / html link? Currently its not launching!

Comment: look at @DonaldJansen post

Comment: if you see my comment below I have tried to add this into my code but it doesn't do anything :(